# Método GET não acessa dados no mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Criei schema.js para consumir dados de um pequeno banco em MongoDB
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

```
//create schema
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var restorationSchema = new Schema({
    point_slug: { type: String, default: true },
    coordinates: { type: String, default: true },
    data: { type: Date, contentType: Number, default: true }
})

restorationSchema.virtual("id").get(function() {
    return this._id;
});

// exporto este módulo
const points = mongoose.model("points", restorationSchema);

module.exports = points;
```

E subi um servidor local para rodar em node no backend

```
const express = require("express");
const points = require("./schema.js");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const db = require("./repository.js");

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
const MONGO_URL = "mongodb://localhost:27017/restoration";
// padrao: mongodb://dominio:porta/database

db.connect(MONGO_URL)
console.log('connect to mongodb')

const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get("/points", (req, res) => {
    points.find((error, response) => {
        // preciso tratar o erro, caso ocorra
        if (error) {
            // caso tenha algum erro
            return res.status(500).send(error);
        }
        // caso contrário, envio o retorno
        res.status(200).send(response);
    });
})

app.get("/points/:id", (req, res) => {
    points.findById(
        req.params.id,

        function(err, point) {
            if (err) return res.send(err);

            if (!point) return res.status(404).send({});
            console.log('*** point.id:', point.id)
            res.send(point);
        }
    );
});
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Ouvindo na porta ${PORT}...`));
```

Porém, quando acesso a url para verificar os dados da collection 'points' dentro do banco usando a url no localhost//5000/points, obtenho essa mengam de erro a qual nao sei decifrar/compreender.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara(o) `.send(error);` não emitiu o erro no "body" da resposta HTTP?

Comment: Coloquei uma imagem para demonstrar o erro,@GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: Não precisava de uma imagem, poderia selecionar e postar o erro diretamente, recomendo leitura: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7816/3635

Comment: Obrigada pela dica

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creio que você tentou definir `true` em um esquema que esperava um valor do tipo `Date`:

```
data: { type: Date, contentType: Number, default: true }
```

Provavelmente o que deseja é a "data atual", para isso defina no default o `Date.now`:

```
data: { type: Date, contentType: Number, default: Date.now }
```

Comment: Mudei o schema segundo tua sugestão.Acesso URL 'localhost://5000/points e dá erro de GET inda, não sei oq posso ser

Comment: Ajustei e consegui, muito obrigada =)

Comment: @LilianGuimarães por favor, marque a resposta como correta. Obrigado!